# ASP.Net .Config : Saving Custom Config Sections

Tags: asp.net

I create new config section for my web app. How could i save it when i modified runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [Web Deployment Projects here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you change the web.config at runtime, it will cause an AppDomain reset, causing your web application to start over again, and your users to lose any work in progress.

Why do you want to change it at runtime, and what do you actually want to change?